# A question related to an inequality involving two entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I am currently trying to solve the following problem from a previous qualifying exam.

> Let $\alpha,\beta: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be two non-constant
> entire functions with exactly the same zeroes of the same order.
> Assume that, for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $|\alpha(z)|\leq
>  (1+|z|)^5|\beta(z)|$ and $\alpha(0)=1, \beta(0)=2$. Express $\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$.

I know that if an analytic function $f$ has a zero at $z=a$, then we can write $f(z)=(z-a)^mf_1(z)$, where $f_1$ is analytic and $f_1(a)\neq 0$. But I am not sure how to proceed further. Any help/hint will be very useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hint: try arguing that $\frac{\alpha(z)}{\beta(z)}$ implies an entire function that must be a polynomial function.  Then examine what zeros that polynomial could have.

Comment: look at $\alpha/\beta$ which is entire by hypothesis and bounded by a polynomial so it a polynomial and one that has no zeroes also by hypothesis...